# How to prove that a finite set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I rigorously prove that a finite set is countable?

A set is countable if there exists a bijective mapping from this set to that of natural numbers.

Please anyone help me to prove it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, it wants you to create a bijection from a fixed finite set and a subset of $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: If you say that a set is countable if it is finite there is nothing to prove. A finite set is countable by definition. If your definition of "countable" is different, please give details and we may be able to help.

Comment: If "A set is countable if it is either finite or enumerable" is your definition of countable, then it is true by definition that a finite set is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely want to appeal to the more rigorous definition of countability, namely that a set $S$ is countable if there is an injective function $f : S \to \mathbb{N}$. That is, you must show that every item in $S$ can be assigned to a unique natural number. Because $S$ is finite, this means that there are at most $k$ such elements in $S$. The rest of the "proof" is the trivial act of creating such an assignment for each element of $S$.