# Prove that all subsets of countable sets are countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is basically a problem of my assignment, it says...

> A set is said to be countable if it is either finite or there is an enumeration(list) of the set. Then prove that **All subsets of countable sets are countable**.

While proving the above, do I have to prove all these 3 cases separately?

- Finite subset of a finite set is countable.
- Finite subset of a countably infinite set is countable.
- Infinite subset of a countably infinite set is countable.

This is my confusion. And if we want to prove that a set $S$ is countable, we have to show that the function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$ is a bijection. Using it, I can prove the 3rd part(infinite subset of countably infinite set); but how can I use this definition to prove the 1st two? Or, if I show that a finite set is countable, will that be enough to say that the 1st two are true?

Please anyone help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some authors use the term "countable" to only refer to infinite sets for which there exists a bijective function with the natural numbers.  Other authors, like the author of the assignment you are referring to, use the term "countable" to refer to any sets (*finite or infinite*) for which there exists an *injective* function to the natural numbers.  I.e. the first author means that a countable set has the *same* cardinality as the natural numbers while the second author means that a countable set has cardinality *less than or equal to* that of the natural numbers.

Comment: According to your definition, a finite set is countable.  Thus there are countable sets for which there can be no bijection with $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Since finite subsets are countable by definition, you do not have to prove anything.

For infinite subsets,  you consider the sub-sequence formed by terms of your subset and ignoring the terms which are not in your subset.

Answer (score -1):

For finite subsets, it would be sufficient (given your definition) to say that any finite subset is countable. However, a more rigorous proof will follow my answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233599/how-to-prove-that-a-finite-set-is-countable/3233606#3233606).